# How do I change the font-size of a bootstrap-select drop-down menu?

Tags: python, html, django, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-select

I tried to set a separate css class to overide the style of the dropdown menu. However, it's not working.

```
#form.py
class fundForm(forms.Form):

    fund = forms.ChoiceField(choices=FUND, required=True, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'selectpicker .selectStyle'}))

    class META:
        model = fundList  

#html
    .selectStyle{
        font-size: 5px
    }
```

Comment: So did any of the answers help you to achieve your goal?

Answer (score 0):

when you specify a class in the DOM, you do not use the `.`, only for accessing it in CSS (or jQuery). change `'selectpicker .selectStyle'` to `'selectpicker selectStyle'`, that should do the trick.

```
fund = forms.ChoiceField(choices=FUND, required=True, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'selectpicker selectStyle'}))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help masterfloda. But it's still not working. Can I set style directly to the attrs field?

Comment: You could (as in hansTheFranz' answer) but inline styles are considered really bad practice. If you take a look at your HTML code the `<select>` should have both classes, `selectpicker selectStyle`. If the font-size is still not 5px, it probably gets overridden by another style, you might want to set the style cascading path accordingly or just use `5px !important`

Comment: haha you should post that under my answer. You are right with the inline styles, but I mentioned it in the post and referred that it should be done in the forms.py ;)